# Google Sheets Shirk Text to Fit Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to get text to auto-resize to fit within its cell with Google Sheets. I have cell widths set to a specific size and have things like emails and job titles that can get pretty long.

I know that Google Sheets doesn't natively support Shrink Text to Fit (WHY!!!!!!) like Excel does but is there a script I can run that will achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 7):

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for automatically resize the font size for fitting in the cell width in the Spreadsheet service. So in this case, it is required to think of the workaround. But the direction for calculating the length of texts in the unit of pixel cannot be directly used. Because as a test case, when I compared the text length (pixel) calculated from the font size and the cell width (pixel), those were different. By this, in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround using other direction. The base flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve the cell width.
2. Automatically resizing the cell width using `autoResizeColumn`.
3. Calculate the ratio of the original width and the resized width of the cell.
4. Change the font size using the ratio.

By this flow, the text length to fit in the cell width can be automatically adjusted. When this flow is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script and set `targetRange`. And run the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  const autoResizeFont = (range, toLarge) => {
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const ss = sheet.getParent();
    const startColumn = range.getColumn();
    const endColumn = range.getColumn() + range.getNumColumns();
    const startRow = range.getRow();
    const endRow = range.getRow() + range.getNumRows();
    const columnObj = [];
    for (let c = startColumn; c < endColumn; c++) {
      columnObj.push({
        column: c,
        width: sheet.getColumnWidth(c)
      });
    }
    const tempSheet = ss.insertSheet("tempForAutoresizeFont");
    sheet.activate();
    const tempRange = tempSheet.getRange("A1");
    for (let r = startRow; r < endRow; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < columnObj.length; c++) {
        const srcRange = sheet.getRange(r, columnObj[c].column);
        tempSheet.setColumnWidth(1, columnObj[c].width);
        srcRange.copyTo(tempRange);
        tempSheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
        const resizedWidth = tempSheet.getColumnWidth(1);
        tempSheet.setColumnWidth(1, columnObj[c].width);
        const ratio = columnObj[c].width / resizedWidth;
        if (ratio > 1 && !toLarge) continue;
        const fontSize = srcRange.getFontSize();
        srcRange.setFontSize(Math.ceil(fontSize * ratio));
      }
    }
    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  }

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const targetRange = "A1:A6";
  const toLarge = true;
  autoResizeFont(sheet.getRange(targetRange), toLarge);
}
```

- In this sample script, a temporal sheet is created and the ratio of the original width and the resized width of the cell is calculated using the temporal sheet.
- When `toLarge` is `true`, when the text length is smaller than the cell width, the font size of the text becomes large. By this, the text length is matched to the cell width. When `toLarge` is `false`, when the text length is smaller than the cell width, the font size of the text not changed.

#### Result:

In this demonstration, the lengths of texts in the cells "A1:A6" are matched to the cell width by changing the font size. In this case, `toLarge` is `true`.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this case, the font size for `setFontSize(size)` is "Integer". By this, the text length might not be exactly the same because the font size is required to be the integer type. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [autoResizeColumn(columnPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#autoresizecolumncolumnposition)
- [setFontSize(size)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontsizesize)

Comment: This is great but how do I do this without changing the row height or making any text larger?

Comment: @Adam Ogden Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, please run the script as `const toLarge = false;`.

Comment: @Adam Ogden Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: I didn't know how to run scripts in Spreadsheets. Useful: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs
Quick use of this code: Tools -> Script Editor -> paste above into Code.gs. Change the constants at the bottom of script (sheet to your sheet, targetRange to your cells), then Run.  Google will warn you that they haven't verified the project.
This script doesn't consider cell height, just width. This can make ToLarge fail on you. I'd suggest setting your font to being max cell height valid, then run without toLarge.