# Script to reduce font size to fit cell width (and height) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, font-size

I want to use a script to automatically adjust the font size of multiple cells that are mostly populated via formula and have dynamic values. This will save me a tonne of time formatting these individual cells.

I saw what looked like a great answer regarding this on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62705769/google-sheets-shirk-text-to-fit-script), but when I tried to run the script I get this error. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null". Unfortunately I am a brand new StackOverflow user and so I don't have enough reputation to comment on that post...

Important notes:

- I have multiple non-contiguous ranges I need to apply this font size
  shrinking to.
- Some of the cells containing the text are merged cells

I am quite new to javascript/apps scripts but I'm a fast learner and I would really appreciate any guidance you can provide.

The solution code from the other post is copied below to save jumping back and forth between windows. Thanks so much!

```
function myFunction() {
  const autoResizeFont = (range, toLarge) => {
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const ss = sheet.getParent();
    const startColumn = range.getColumn();
    const endColumn = range.getColumn() + range.getNumColumns();
    const startRow = range.getRow();
    const endRow = range.getRow() + range.getNumRows();
    const columnObj = [];
    for (let c = startColumn; c < endColumn; c++) {
      columnObj.push({
        column: c,
        width: sheet.getColumnWidth(c)
      });
    }
    const tempSheet = ss.insertSheet("tempForAutoresizeFont");
    sheet.activate();
    const tempRange = tempSheet.getRange("A1");
    for (let r = startRow; r < endRow; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < columnObj.length; c++) {
        const srcRange = sheet.getRange(r, columnObj[c].column);
        tempSheet.setColumnWidth(1, columnObj[c].width);
        srcRange.copyTo(tempRange);
        tempSheet.autoResizeColumn(1);
        const resizedWidth = tempSheet.getColumnWidth(1);
        tempSheet.setColumnWidth(1, columnObj[c].width);
        const ratio = columnObj[c].width / resizedWidth;
        if (ratio > 1 && !toLarge) continue;
        const fontSize = srcRange.getFontSize();
        srcRange.setFontSize(Math.ceil(fontSize * ratio));
      }
    }
    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  }

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const targetRange = "A1:A6";
  const toLarge = false;
  autoResizeFont(sheet.getRange(targetRange), toLarge);
}
```

Comment: You might want  o consider using a rangeList you can search for it in the google documentation.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About your question, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null`. When I test it, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: In which line of code are you getting that error? In the one that says ```const sheet = range.getSheet();```?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the following changes to that example:

```
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//change the sheet name to whatever you want
  const targetRange = sheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();//make this change and you can just select the range you want and run myFunction();
```

Read the comments above