# Script to convert "Do not autofit" property to "Shrink text on overflow" in creted Google Slides using Autocrate add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-slides

I tried [Autocrate](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autocrat/539341275670) `("Document merge tool that creates PDF or shared Documents from spreadsheet data")` to create multiple Google Slides from a Google Slide template I made (it have one slide, it's a certificate). The template have multiple text boxes with different dimensions and font sizes and all of them are set to "Shrink text on overflow".

Autocrate makes a copy of this certificate template and starts to fill data from the Google Sheet that has the data (names, age..etc). and put them inside a folder in Google Drive.

All the text boxes in the newly generated Google Slides have "Do not autofit" property! Autocrate don't retain "Shrink text on overflow" property when making a copy of the Google Slides template.

This is a comment from Autocrate's developer in Google Groups ([Source](https://groups.google.com/g/nv-autocrat-add-on/c/Tgh5t1Y57ak/m/q_byVomwBAAJ)):

> Autocrat makes a copy of the template and then modifies it.
> I don't know how to fix it except to edit the output and add the setting.  I'm not a script writer so I don't know if a script can be written.
>
> I'm guessing that there is something wrong with the Google command to copy a presentation.  I have my doubts if there is anything that NewVisions can do.

I tested Google Slides by making a manual copy of the template and it seems to me Google Slides retain "Shrink text on overflow" property! so looks like there is something form the end of Autocrate.

While I can't do any thing to Autocrate now, I thought of a Google Sheet template that I give it two links of Google Drive folders, Source folder and Destination folder. The source folder has all the newly generated Google Slides from Autocrate and an Apps Script starts to make all text boxes "Shrink text on overflow" in all Google Slides and save them to a new folder (Destination folder) or even overwrite the files in Source folder.

This idea came to mind from this developer Carl Arrowsmith, he made a Google Sheet template where it converts Google files (docs, sheets, slides..etc) to pdfs. You give it the link of the source folder that has the Google files, and give it a destination folder link to save the pdfs of the files there. He made a YouTube video explain how to use the scrip ([Make PDF files from a folder of files in Google Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7wK-RGU3rA)) And put the Google Sheet template in the video description, here is the code written by him in Apps Script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Options')
      .addItem('Make PDF files in folder','gdocToPDF')

  .addToUi();
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }

function gdocToPDF() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var sworkingsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var idrange = sworkingsheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2);
   
    var documentRootfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getIdFromUrl(idrange.getCell(1, 2).getValue())) // replace this with the ID of the folder that contains the documents you want to convert
    var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(getIdFromUrl(idrange.getCell(2, 2).getValue())); // replace this with the ID of the folder that the PDFs should be put in. 

    var documentRootFiles = documentRootfolder.getFiles()

    while(documentRootFiles.hasNext()) {
        createPDF(documentRootFiles.next().getId(), pdfFolder.getId(), function (fileID, folderID) {
            if (fileID) createPDFfile(fileID, folderID);
        })
    }
    ui.alert("Process Complete");
}


function createPDF(fileID, folderID, callback) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var templateName = templateFile.getName();
    
    var existingPDFs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFiles();

    //in case no files exist
    if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
        return callback(fileID, folderID);
    }

    for (; existingPDFs.hasNext();) {

        var existingPDFfile = existingPDFs.next();
        var existingPDFfileName = existingPDFfile.getName();
        if (existingPDFfileName == templateName + ".pdf") {
            Logger.log("PDF exists already. No PDF created")
            return callback();
        }
        if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
            Logger.log("PDF is created")
            return callback(fileID, folderID)
        }
    }
}

function createPDFfile(fileID, folderID) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

    var fileName = templateFile.getName().replace(".", ""); //otherwise filename will be shortened after full stop    
    newPDFFile.setName(fileName + ".pdf");
}
```

Also, I saw this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709196/9907495 from [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) where it discuss shrink the text in Google Sheets to fit cells size. Maybe it's related to my case here not related. But is there a workaround to generate Google Slides with Autocrate and keep the "Shrink text on overflow" property? or even converting text boxes to this property after generating the Google Slides with a script like I mentioned before?

Addition: Looks like shrink text in Apps Script have a bug!! Sources:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191389037

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189153562

What did you try and what were you expecting?

Manually adjusteding the text boxes to "Shrink text on overflow" property after the Google Slides generated form Autocrate!

Comment: Sorry to [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mention you here, but I need your opinion if possible in a workaround for this since you have a lot of background in this matter .